# Internal Server Error & TypeError: Cannot destructure property `semester1` of 'undefined' or 'null'

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, express, axios

Newb here, I am trying do a POST request using axios from the react front end. I have tried to use express to perform operations on my postgreSQL database directly but it did not work out. Thus, I used axios to GET data, which worked, so I hoped that axios' POST would work as well. However, I am getting the result:

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property `semester1` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
```

in the localhost, the error resulted in:

```
500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { Add } from '../styledComponents/scaddGrades'

const apiURL = `http://localhost:5000/grades`;

class addGrades extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            sem1: 0,
            sem2: 0,
            sem3: 0,
            sem4: 0,
            final: 0,
        }

    this.onButtonClick = this.onButtonClick.bind(this);
    this.inputHandler = this.inputHandler.bind(this);

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

onButtonClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Add Grades")
}

handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const data = {
        semester1: this.state.sem1,
        semester2: this.state.sem2,
        semester3: this.state.sem3,
        semester4: this.state.sem4,
        finalgrades: this.state.final
    }

    axios.post(apiURL, { data })
        .then(res => {
            console.log("response: ", res)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
}

inputHandler(e) {
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
    console.log(this.state)
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Add id="AddGrades" onClick={this.onButtonClick}>Add Grades</Add>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input type="text" name="sem1" onChange={this.inputHandler} />
                <input type="text" name="sem2" onChange={this.inputHandler} />
                <input type="text" name="sem3" onChange={this.inputHandler} />
                <input type="text" name="sem4" onChange={this.inputHandler} />
                <input type="text" name="final" onChange={this.inputHandler} />
                <button type="submit"> Add</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
}

export default addGrades;
```

Edit: Here's my code for api (using express)

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const { pool } = require('./config')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(cors())

const getGrades = (request, response) => {
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM grades', (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            throw error
        }
        response.status(200).json(results.rows)
        response.end(JSON.stringify(results))
    })

}

const addGradesToDatabase = (request, response) => {
    const { semester1, semester2, semester3, semester4, finalgrades } = request.bodyParser

    pool.query('INSERT INTO grades (semester1, semester2, semester3, semester4, finalgrades) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)', [semester1, semester2, semester3, semester4, finalgrades], error => {
        if (error) {
            throw error
        }

        response.status(201).json({ status: 'success', message: 'Grades added' })
    })
}

const updateGrades = (request, response) => {
    const id = parseInt(request.params.id)
    const { semester1, semester2, semester3, semester4, finalgrades } = request.bodyParser

    pool.query('UPDATE grades SET semester1 = $1, semester2 = $2, semester3 = $3, semester4 = $4, semester5 = $5 WHERE id = $7',
        [semester1, semester2, semester3, semester4, finalgrades, id], (error, results) => {
            if (error) {
                throw error
            }
            response.status(200).send(`grades modified with ID: ${id}`)
        })
}

const deleteGrades = (request, response) => {
    const id = parseInt(request.params.id)

    pool.query('DELETE FROM grades WHERE id = $1', [id], (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            throw error
        }
        response.status(200).send(`grades modified with ID: ${id}`)
    })
}

app
    .route('/grades')
    .get(getGrades)
    .post(addGradesToDatabase)
    .put(updateGrades)
    .delete(deleteGrades)

module.exports = {
    getGrades,
    addGradesToDatabase,
    updateGrades,
    deleteGrades,
}

//Start Server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening at port: ${PORT}`)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that `request.bodyParser` is undefined, which makes sense, since there's no such property on request object. Most likely it'd be `body`:

```
const { semester1, semester2, semester3, semester4, finalgrades } = request.body;
```

I assume you did check the [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html) for body-parser library?

Answer (score 0):

you need to spread the state before the setting the value and also specify the Content-Type

```
 import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { Add } from '../styledComponents/scaddGrades'

const apiURL = `http://localhost:5000/grades`;

class addGrades extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            sem1: 0,
            sem2: 0,
            sem3: 0,
            sem4: 0,
            final: 0,
        }

    this.onButtonClick = this.onButtonClick.bind(this);
    this.inputHandler = this.inputHandler.bind(this);

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

onButtonClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Add Grades")
}

handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const data = {
        semester1: this.state.sem1,
        semester2: this.state.sem2,
        semester3: this.state.sem3,
        semester4: this.state.sem4,
        finalgrades: this.state.final
    }

  const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      }
    };

    axios.post(apiURL,data,config)
        .then(res => {
            console.log("response: ", res)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
}

inputHandler(e) {
    this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
    console.log(this.state)
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Add id="AddGrades" onClick={this.onButtonClick}>Add Grades</Add>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input type="text" name="sem1" onChange={this.inputHandler} />
                <input type="text" name="sem2" onChange={this.inputHandler} />
                <input type="text" name="sem3" onChange={this.inputHandler} />
                <input type="text" name="sem4" onChange={this.inputHandler} />
                <input type="text" name="final" onChange={this.inputHandler} />
                <button type="submit"> Add</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
}

export default addGrades;
```

Comment: What do you mean spread the state? and could you show me how I can specify the content type? I'm sorry I'm very new to this.

Comment: You need to maintain the current state before making a change to part of the state, In the headers you specify the type of data i.e `Content-Type` that you are sending, see if the above code resolves the issue

Comment: Hi, I tried and the issue was not resolved. The error "cannot destructure property remains the same". Maybe the problem lies in the api code. I've just posted it above. Thank you for helping.